# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The code below works out in copying every other element of 'str' in 'temp' but if I only increment '*str' once it gives me a segmentation fault(core dumped).
I was trying to copy all of the even letters of the string into the 'even' array, same with the odd letters.('even' being the second letter, the fourth, the sixth, etc.) But I realized that when I increment it stays incremented. I don't really know how to work around that so I tried storing the letters in a different array within the function but got a segmentation fault. I don't understand why incrementing twice is ok but once is not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

void encrypt(const char*);

int main(void)
{
    char str[N];
    printf("Please enter a message: ");
    gets(str);

    encrypt(&str);
return 0;
}

void encrypt(const char *str)
{
    int i, j, length;
    char temp[N], odd[N], even[N];

    length = strlen(str);

    for (j = 0; *str < *str + length; *str++, *str++, j++)
    {
        temp[j] = *str;
    }
    printf("%s", temp);
}
```

Comment: How do you know `j` never exceeds `N`?

Comment: `*str < *str + length` Explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what this line does.

Comment: And show how you call `encrypt`.

Comment: this expression: `*str < *str + length;` says to take the char pointed to by `str` and check if it is less than that same char + some value.  it 'might' exit the `for()` statement IF the value wrapped around beyond 0xFF, but this is VERY unlikely and certainly not what you intended

Comment: @DYZ
 N is set to 100. Whatever the user enters into str will be less than 100 so the length will be less than 100. The for loop will only go as long as '*str' is less than whatever the length is

Comment: @n.m. I honestly don't know how to explain this. All I know is that it works and that I can't do what I would normally do with a for loop if I wasn't using a pointer. I also don't know how to just pass the array     str as an argument without using a pointer.

Comment: Basically `*str < *str + length` is `A < A + B`. Which is equivalent to `B > 0`, which is `length > 0`, which makes no sense as loop a condition.

Comment: "don't know how to explain this" Then hit backspace as many times as needed for being able to explain what's left. "it works" Apparently not very well.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you actually wanted to write this:

```
for (j = 0; str < str + length; *str++, *str++, j++)
```

which could be written like this which is a bit more clear:

```
for (j = 0; str < str + length; str++, str++, j++)
```

But this is wrong anyway because `str < str + length` is always true.

This is what you need:

```
for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
  temp[j] = *str;
  str += 2;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the code samples are not equivalent. While `str < str + length` is always false, `j< length` is not.

Comment: This works but there are a few stray random characters at the end. Like if I enter 'Hello'  this gets stored in 'temp' 'Hello▒a'